# How to connect to Amazon S3 though WSo2 MI using connector?

Tags: wso2, wso2-enterprise-integrator, wso2-micro-integrator

I need to connect to Amazon S3. I am using connector:amazons3-connector-2.0.3.zip as I am working Wso2 MI-Integration Studio but I am getting error.
what I get to know that the connector is different for different wso2 versions,I am not sure what exactly will work in MI.

Below is the code:

```
localEntry:

    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <localEntry key="AMAZON_S3_CONNECTION_1" xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse">
        <amazons3.init>
            <awsAccessKeyId>***</awsAccessKeyId>
            <name>AMAZON_S3_CONNECTION_1</name>
            <region>***</region>
            <connectionType>amazons3</connectionType>
            <awsSecretAccessKey>***</awsSecretAccessKey>
        </amazons3.init>
    </localEntry>


    Proxy:

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<proxy name="AmazonConnectivity" startOnLoad="true" transports="http https vfs" xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse">
    <target>
        <inSequence>
            <log level="full">
                <property name="log" value="====before S3===="/>
            </log>
            <amazons3.createBucket configKey="AMAZON_S3_CONNECTION_1">
                <bucketName>testnew</bucketName>
                <bucketRegion>us-east-2</bucketRegion>
                <acl>bucket-owner-full-control</acl>
            </amazons3.createBucket>
            <log level="full">
                <property name="log" value="====After Amazon S3===="/>
            </log>
        </inSequence>
        <outSequence/>
        <faultSequence/>
    </target>
    <parameter name="transport.PollInterval">5</parameter>
    <parameter name="transport.vfs.FileURI">vfs:file:///C:/amazon-s3</parameter>
    <parameter name="transport.vfs.ContentType">text/plain</parameter>
    <parameter name="transport.vfs.ActionAfterProcess">MOVE</parameter>
    <parameter name="transport.vfs.MoveAfterFailure">vfs:file:///C:/failure</parameter>
    <parameter name="transport.vfs.ActionAfterFailure">MOVE</parameter>
    <parameter name="transport.vfs.FileNamePattern">.*.rdy</parameter>
    <parameter name="transport.vfs.MoveAfterProcess">vfs:file:///C:/out</parameter>
</proxy>

Error:
[2022-07-29 12:41:32,562] ERROR {ClassMediatorFactory} - Error in instantiating class : org.wso2.carbon.connector.amazons3.operations.BucketOperations java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: software/amazon/awssdk/services/s3/model/BucketAlreadyExistsException
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructors0(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredConstructors(Class.java:3138)
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Class.java:3343)
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:556)
    at org.apache.synapse.config.xml.ClassMediatorFactory.createSpecificMediator(ClassMediatorFactory.java:110)
    at org.apache.synapse.config.xml.AbstractMediatorFactory.createMediator(AbstractMediatorFactory.java:98)
    at org.apache.synapse.config.xml.MediatorFactoryFinder.getMediator(MediatorFactoryFinder.java:251)
    at org.apache.synapse.config.xml.AbstractListMediatorFactory.addChildren(AbstractListMediatorFactory.java:53)
    at org.apache.synapse.config.xml.TemplateMediatorFactory.createSpecificMediator(TemplateMediatorFactory.java:63)
    at org.apache.synapse.config.xml.AbstractMediatorFactory.createMediator(AbstractMediatorFactory.java:98)
    at org.apache.synapse.config.xml.MediatorFactoryFinder.getMediator(MediatorFactoryFinder.java:251)
    at org.apache.synapse.libraries.model.LibraryArtifact$TemplateArtifactFile.build(LibraryArtifact.java:196)
    at org.apache.synapse.libraries.model.LibraryArtifact.loadComponentsInto(LibraryArtifact.java:101)
    at org.apache.synapse.libraries.model.SynapseLibrary.loadLibrary(SynapseLibrary.java:144)
    at org.apache.synapse.libraries.model.SynapseLibrary.loadLibrary(SynapseLibrary.java:129)
    at org.apache.synapse.libraries.util.LibDeployerUtils.loadLibArtifacts(LibDeployerUtils.java:340)
    at org.wso2.micro.integrator.initializer.deployment.synapse.deployer.SynapseAppDeployer.addImport(SynapseAppDeployer.java:567)
    at org.wso2.micro.integrator.initializer.deployment.synapse.deployer.SynapseAppDeployer.addImport(SynapseAppDeployer.java:510)
    at org.wso2.micro.integrator.initializer.deployment.synapse.deployer.SynapseAppDeployer.updateStatus(SynapseAppDeployer.java:470)
    at org.wso2.micro.integrator.initializer.deployment.synapse.deployer.SynapseAppDeployer.deploySynapseLibrary(SynapseAppDeployer.java:413)
    at org.wso2.micro.integrator.initializer.deployment.synapse.deployer.SynapseAppDeployer.deployArtifacts(SynapseAppDeployer.java:134)
    at org.wso2.micro.integrator.initializer.deployment.application.deployer.CappDeployer.deployCarbonApps(CappDeployer.java:163)
    at org.wso2.micro.integrator.initializer.deployment.application.deployer.CappDeployer.deploy(CappDeployer.java:121)
    at org.apache.axis2.deployment.repository.util.DeploymentFileData.deploy(DeploymentFileData.java:136)
    at org.apache.axis2.deployment.DeploymentEngine.doDeploy(DeploymentEngine.java:807)
    at org.apache.axis2.deployment.repository.util.WSInfoList.update(WSInfoList.java:153)
    at org.apache.axis2.deployment.RepositoryListener.update(RepositoryListener.java:377)
    at org.apache.axis2.deployment.RepositoryListener.checkServices(RepositoryListener.java:254)
    at org.apache.axis2.deployment.DeploymentEngine.loadServices(DeploymentEngine.java:135)
    at org.wso2.micro.core.CarbonAxisConfigurator.deployServices(CarbonAxisConfigurator.java:530)
    at org.wso2.micro.integrator.initializer.deployment.AppDeployerServiceComponent.invokeRegisteredDeployers(AppDeployerServiceComponent.java:213)
    at org.wso2.micro.integrator.initializer.deployment.AppDeployerServiceComponent.activate(AppDeployerServiceComponent.java:82)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.model.ServiceComponent.activate(ServiceComponent.java:260)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.model.ServiceComponentProp.activate(ServiceComponentProp.java:146)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.model.ServiceComponentProp.build(ServiceComponentProp.java:345)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.InstanceProcess.buildComponent(InstanceProcess.java:620)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.InstanceProcess.buildComponents(InstanceProcess.java:197)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.Resolver.getEligible(Resolver.java:343)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.SCRManager.serviceChanged(SCRManager.java:222)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.serviceregistry.FilteredServiceListener.serviceChanged(FilteredServiceListener.java:113)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.BundleContextImpl.dispatchEvent(BundleContextImpl.java:985)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager.dispatchEvent(EventManager.java:234)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.ListenerQueue.dispatchEventSynchronous(ListenerQueue.java:151)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.serviceregistry.ServiceRegistry.publishServiceEventPrivileged(ServiceRegistry.java:866)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.serviceregistry.ServiceRegistry.publishServiceEvent(ServiceRegistry.java:804)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.serviceregistry.ServiceRegistrationImpl.register(ServiceRegistrationImpl.java:130)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.serviceregistry.ServiceRegistry.registerService(ServiceRegistry.java:228)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.BundleContextImpl.registerService(BundleContextImpl.java:525)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.BundleContextImpl.registerService(BundleContextImpl.java:544)
    at org.wso2.micro.integrator.initializer.ServiceBusInitializer.activate(ServiceBusInitializer.java:192)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.model.ServiceComponent.activate(ServiceComponent.java:235)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.model.ServiceComponentProp.activate(ServiceComponentProp.java:146)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.model.ServiceComponentProp.build(ServiceComponentProp.java:345)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.InstanceProcess.buildComponent(InstanceProcess.java:620)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.InstanceProcess.buildComponents(InstanceProcess.java:197)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.Resolver.getEligible(Resolver.java:343)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.SCRManager.serviceChanged(SCRManager.java:222)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.serviceregistry.FilteredServiceListener.serviceChanged(FilteredServiceListener.java:113)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.BundleContextImpl.dispatchEvent(BundleContextImpl.java:985)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager.dispatchEvent(EventManager.java:234)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.ListenerQueue.dispatchEventSynchronous(ListenerQueue.java:151)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.serviceregistry.ServiceRegistry.publishServiceEventPrivileged(ServiceRegistry.java:866)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.serviceregistry.ServiceRegistry.publishServiceEvent(ServiceRegistry.java:804)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.serviceregistry.ServiceRegistrationImpl.register(ServiceRegistrationImpl.java:130)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.serviceregistry.ServiceRegistry.registerService(ServiceRegistry.java:228)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.BundleContextImpl.registerService(BundleContextImpl.java:525)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.BundleContextImpl.registerService(BundleContextImpl.java:544)
    at org.wso2.micro.integrator.ntask.core.internal.TasksDSComponent.activate(TasksDSComponent.java:147)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.model.ServiceComponent.activate(ServiceComponent.java:260)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.model.ServiceComponentProp.activate(ServiceComponentProp.java:146)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.model.ServiceComponentProp.build(ServiceComponentProp.java:345)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.InstanceProcess.buildComponent(InstanceProcess.java:620)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.InstanceProcess.buildComponents(InstanceProcess.java:197)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.Resolver.buildNewlySatisfied(Resolver.java:473)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.Resolver.enableComponents(Resolver.java:217)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.SCRManager.performWork(SCRManager.java:816)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.SCRManager$QueuedJob.dispatch(SCRManager.java:783)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.WorkThread.run(WorkThread.java:89)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.util.impl.tpt.threadpool.Executor.run(Executor.java:70)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: software.amazon.awssdk.services.s3.model.BucketAlreadyExistsException
    at org.apache.axis2.classloader.MultiParentClassLoader.loadClass(MultiParentClassLoader.java:279)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:521)
    ... 91 more

[2022-07-29 12:41:32,564] ERROR {SynapseAppDeployer} - Unable to update status for :  {org.wso2.carbon.connector}amazons3 :: Template configuration : null cannot be builtfor Synapse Library artifact : deleteBucket org.apache.synapse.deployers.SynapseArtifactDeploymentException: Template configuration : null cannot be builtfor Synapse Library artifact : deleteBucket
    at org.apache.synapse.libraries.model.LibraryArtifact$TemplateArtifactFile.build(LibraryArtifact.java:201)
    at org.apache.synapse.libraries.model.LibraryArtifact.loadComponentsInto(LibraryArtifact.java:101)
    at org.apache.synapse.libraries.model.SynapseLibrary.loadLibrary(SynapseLibrary.java:144)
    at org.apache.synapse.libraries.model.SynapseLibrary.loadLibrary(SynapseLibrary.java:129)
    at org.apache.synapse.libraries.util.LibDeployerUtils.loadLibArtifacts(LibDeployerUtils.java:340)
    at org.wso2.micro.integrator.initializer.deployment.synapse.deployer.SynapseAppDeployer.addImport(SynapseAppDeployer.java:567)
    at org.wso2.micro.integrator.initializer.deployment.synapse.deployer.SynapseAppDeployer.addImport(SynapseAppDeployer.java:510)
    at org.wso2.micro.integrator.initializer.deployment.synapse.deployer.SynapseAppDeployer.updateStatus(SynapseAppDeployer.java:470)
    at org.wso2.micro.integrator.initializer.deployment.synapse.deployer.SynapseAppDeployer.deploySynapseLibrary(SynapseAppDeployer.java:413)
    at org.wso2.micro.integrator.initializer.deployment.synapse.deployer.SynapseAppDeployer.deployArtifacts(SynapseAppDeployer.java:134)
    at org.wso2.micro.integrator.initializer.deployment.application.deployer.CappDeployer.deployCarbonApps(CappDeployer.java:163)
    at org.wso2.micro.integrator.initializer.deployment.application.deployer.CappDeployer.deploy(CappDeployer.java:121)
    at org.apache.axis2.deployment.repository.util.DeploymentFileData.deploy(DeploymentFileData.java:136)
    at org.apache.axis2.deployment.DeploymentEngine.doDeploy(DeploymentEngine.java:807)
    at org.apache.axis2.deployment.repository.util.WSInfoList.update(WSInfoList.java:153)
    at org.apache.axis2.deployment.RepositoryListener.update(RepositoryListener.java:377)
    at org.apache.axis2.deployment.RepositoryListener.checkServices(RepositoryListener.java:254)
    at org.apache.axis2.deployment.DeploymentEngine.loadServices(DeploymentEngine.java:135)
    at org.wso2.micro.core.CarbonAxisConfigurator.deployServices(CarbonAxisConfigurator.java:530)
    at org.wso2.micro.integrator.initializer.deployment.AppDeployerServiceComponent.invokeRegisteredDeployers(AppDeployerServiceComponent.java:213)
    at org.wso2.micro.integrator.initializer.deployment.AppDeployerServiceComponent.activate(AppDeployerServiceComponent.java:82)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.model.ServiceComponent.activate(ServiceComponent.java:260)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.model.ServiceComponentProp.activate(ServiceComponentProp.java:146)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.model.ServiceComponentProp.build(ServiceComponentProp.java:345)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.InstanceProcess.buildComponent(InstanceProcess.java:620)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.InstanceProcess.buildComponents(InstanceProcess.java:197)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.Resolver.getEligible(Resolver.java:343)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.SCRManager.serviceChanged(SCRManager.java:222)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.serviceregistry.FilteredServiceListener.serviceChanged(FilteredServiceListener.java:113)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.BundleContextImpl.dispatchEvent(BundleContextImpl.java:985)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager.dispatchEvent(EventManager.java:234)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.ListenerQueue.dispatchEventSynchronous(ListenerQueue.java:151)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.serviceregistry.ServiceRegistry.publishServiceEventPrivileged(ServiceRegistry.java:866)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.serviceregistry.ServiceRegistry.publishServiceEvent(ServiceRegistry.java:804)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.serviceregistry.ServiceRegistrationImpl.register(ServiceRegistrationImpl.java:130)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.serviceregistry.ServiceRegistry.registerService(ServiceRegistry.java:228)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.BundleContextImpl.registerService(BundleContextImpl.java:525)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.BundleContextImpl.registerService(BundleContextImpl.java:544)
    at org.wso2.micro.integrator.initializer.ServiceBusInitializer.activate(ServiceBusInitializer.java:192)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.model.ServiceComponent.activate(ServiceComponent.java:235)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.model.ServiceComponentProp.activate(ServiceComponentProp.java:146)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.model.ServiceComponentProp.build(ServiceComponentProp.java:345)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.InstanceProcess.buildComponent(InstanceProcess.java:620)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.InstanceProcess.buildComponents(InstanceProcess.java:197)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.Resolver.getEligible(Resolver.java:343)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.SCRManager.serviceChanged(SCRManager.java:222)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.serviceregistry.FilteredServiceListener.serviceChanged(FilteredServiceListener.java:113)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.BundleContextImpl.dispatchEvent(BundleContextImpl.java:985)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager.dispatchEvent(EventManager.java:234)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.ListenerQueue.dispatchEventSynchronous(ListenerQueue.java:151)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.serviceregistry.ServiceRegistry.publishServiceEventPrivileged(ServiceRegistry.java:866)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.serviceregistry.ServiceRegistry.publishServiceEvent(ServiceRegistry.java:804)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.serviceregistry.ServiceRegistrationImpl.register(ServiceRegistrationImpl.java:130)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.serviceregistry.ServiceRegistry.registerService(ServiceRegistry.java:228)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.BundleContextImpl.registerService(BundleContextImpl.java:525)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.BundleContextImpl.registerService(BundleContextImpl.java:544)
    at org.wso2.micro.integrator.ntask.core.internal.TasksDSComponent.activate(TasksDSComponent.java:147)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.model.ServiceComponent.activate(ServiceComponent.java:260)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.model.ServiceComponentProp.activate(ServiceComponentProp.java:146)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.model.ServiceComponentProp.build(ServiceComponentProp.java:345)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.InstanceProcess.buildComponent(InstanceProcess.java:620)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.InstanceProcess.buildComponents(InstanceProcess.java:197)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.Resolver.buildNewlySatisfied(Resolver.java:473)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.Resolver.enableComponents(Resolver.java:217)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.SCRManager.performWork(SCRManager.java:816)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.SCRManager$QueuedJob.dispatch(SCRManager.java:783)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.WorkThread.run(WorkThread.java:89)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.util.impl.tpt.threadpool.Executor.run(Executor.java:70)
Caused by: org.apache.synapse.SynapseException: Error in instantiating class : org.wso2.carbon.connector.amazons3.operations.BucketOperations
    at org.apache.synapse.config.xml.ClassMediatorFactory.createSpecificMediator(ClassMediatorFactory.java:114)
    at org.apache.synapse.config.xml.AbstractMediatorFactory.createMediator(AbstractMediatorFactory.java:98)
    at org.apache.synapse.config.xml.MediatorFactoryFinder.getMediator(MediatorFactoryFinder.java:251)
    at org.apache.synapse.config.xml.AbstractListMediatorFactory.addChildren(AbstractListMediatorFactory.java:53)
    at org.apache.synapse.config.xml.TemplateMediatorFactory.createSpecificMediator(TemplateMediatorFactory.java:63)
    at org.apache.synapse.config.xml.AbstractMediatorFactory.createMediator(AbstractMediatorFactory.java:98)
    at org.apache.synapse.config.xml.MediatorFactoryFinder.getMediator(MediatorFactoryFinder.java:251)
    at org.apache.synapse.libraries.model.LibraryArtifact$TemplateArtifactFile.build(LibraryArtifact.java:196)
    ... 79 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: software/amazon/awssdk/services/s3/model/BucketAlreadyExistsException
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructors0(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredConstructors(Class.java:3138)
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Class.java:3343)
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:556)
    at org.apache.synapse.config.xml.ClassMediatorFactory.createSpecificMediator(ClassMediatorFactory.java:110)
    ... 86 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: software.amazon.awssdk.services.s3.model.BucketAlreadyExistsException
    at org.apache.axis2.classloader.MultiParentClassLoader.loadClass(MultiParentClassLoader.java:279)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:521)
    ... 91 more
```

Can someone share an example on how to do it in Wso2 MI?
and If the code runs in MI will it run in EI as well?

Comment: Have you added the following client libraries? https://ei.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/micro-integrator/references/connectors/amazons3-connector/amazons3-connector-config/#deploying-the-client-libraries

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order for the S3 connector to work, you need to add the following jars to the /lib directory as mentioned in the documentation. https://apim.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/reference/connectors/amazons3-connector/amazons3-connector-config/#deploying-the-client-libraries